# GPU hang when running intensive shaders and iOS animation at same time

Tags: swift, swift4, metal

We have an app where we run some fairly heavy machine learning code on metal. Recently we've seen an uptick in gpu hang errors that seem to coincide with system animations being run (present, UIView.animate) which leads me to believe it has to do with too much load being put on the GPU. Our machine learning code is run on a side thread since it also has some CPU components and it's pretty intensive, afaik UI animations need to be run on the main thread. Wondering if anyone has hit this kind of an issue before and if there are any good workarounds?

```html
2018-12-11 11:38:41.203756-0800 Onyx[46615:7879990] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2)
2018-12-11 11:38:41.203895-0800 Onyx[46615:7879990] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2)
2018-12-11 11:38:41.254021-0800 Onyx[46615:7879990] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
2018-12-11 11:38:41.254058-0800 Onyx[46615:7879990] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
2018-12-11 11:38:41.254090-0800 Onyx[46615:7879990] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
2018-12-11 11:38:41.254100-0800 Onyx[46615:7879990] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
```